# Kafka | Kafka consumer hangs at consumer.poll() | Unexpected error code 2 while fetching data

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We are facing an intermittent issue with our Kafka consumer. It gets stuck at `consumer.poll(100)` method after certain period of time and starts throwing below exception:

> Unexpected error code 2 while fetching data
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseCompletedFetch(Fetcher.java:891),
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:528),
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1154),
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1111)

Below are configs -

```
props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
props.put("group.id", "testGroup");
props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
props.put("key.deserializer", 
"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("value.deserializer", 
"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("max.poll.records", "10");
props.put("metadata.max.age.ms", "10000");
```

The problem seems to get resolved temporarily when we restart it. But after sometime, it again gets stuck.

Can it be related to max.poll.records? If size of 10 records becomes larger than default 1MB, then can it cause the consumer to hang?

Comment: What version of Kafka are you using?

Comment: It is 0.9.0.1 installed

Comment: Since `enabled.auto.commit` is set to `false`, there's no need to set the commit interval.

Answer (score 0):

The error code 2 arises when the message is corrupted or exceeds the valid size.

Refer the following link for reference on error codes: https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#protocol_error_codes

So, yes it can be related to max.poll.records. Either reduce the max.poll.records value or increase the default record size from 1 MB.

Also, the property **max.poll.records** takes a value of type Int. You have given a value of type String. Try changing that too.

Comment: If max.poll.records can be potential issue, then how can same consumer be able to read data upon restart. Also, we are not receiving any record larger than 1MB. Let's assume only 5 records fit into 1MB limit, then won't the consumer poll only 5 records instead of 10?